# All my files are gone

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to ubuntu, i tried to install it from a usb drive created by LiLi in windows, now when i reboot and start installing ubuntu, i did not get " install alongside windows 8 " option for a reason, i rushed things in and created Logical drive over the drive that has windows 8 on it.

After installed ubuntu successfully, everything is gone, my partitions , even the recovery partition.

i am not asking to do all the work for me, i really tried couple of things, but before processed , i want to know if there is a hope for me or is it completely gone!?

Comment: Firstly, stop using the disk (reboot into a Live USB session) and then look at previous questions on the topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery

Answer (score 0):

There is hope for you. There are programs online that can restore partitions after they have been formatted and are completely "gone."

An example is this: http://www.partition-recovery.com/

I've never made your specific mistake, but I did accidentally format the wrong partition and loose all of my files, and a software like this brought it back. I would recommend finding a software that offers a trial edition to test to see if it can access some of your lost files, before running out and purchasing\"downloading" something.